# Updates for tf::MessageFilter example in geometry_tutorials

Tags: ros, tf-tutorial

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I was trying to work through the tf tutorials, and had some issues when I got to the part about message filters. The tutorial refers to "turtle_tf_sensor.launch" which is not in the package. I am using Fuerte, and it appears that the file [is also missing from Groovy](http://www.ros.org/wiki/tf/Tutorials/Using%20Stamped%20datatypes%20with%20tf%3A%3AMessageFilter). Also, this issue was [previously raised](http://answers.ros.org/question/9512/where-did-turtle_tf_sensorlaunch-go/), but I cannot see it being fixed.

I have recreated the missing launch file, and a python node that it runs, based on code from [Box Turtle](https://code.ros.org/trac/ros-pkg/browser/branches/trunk_boxturtle/stacks/ros_pkg_tutorials/turtle_tf?rev=29778).

If you want me to submit a patch somewhere else please advise.

**Missing file 1:**
geometry_tutorials/turtle_tf/launch/turtle_tf_sensor.launch

```
<launch>
    <include file="$(find turtle_tf)/launch/turtle_tf_demo.launch" />
    <node name="turtle_pose_stamped_publisher" pkg="turtle_tf" type="turtle_tf_message_broadcaster.py" respawn="false" output="screen" /> 
</launch>
```

**Missing file 2:**
geometry_tutorials/turtle_tf/nodes/turtle_tf_message_broadcaster.py

[Note: this was modified from Box Turtle code to use Point instead of Pose to match the tutorial code]

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import roslib
roslib.load_manifest('turtle_tf')
import rospy

import tf
import turtlesim.msg, turtlesim.srv
from geometry_msgs.msg import PointStamped, Point
from std_msgs.msg import Header

class PointPublisher:
    def handle_turtle_pose(self, msg, turtlename):
        self.pub.publish(PointStamped(Header(0, rospy.rostime.get_rostime(), "/world"), Point(msg.x, msg.y, 0)))

    def __init__(self):
        self.turtlename = "turtle3" #rospy.get_param('~turtle')
        self.sub = rospy.Subscriber('/%s/pose' % self.turtlename,
                         turtlesim.msg.Pose,
                         self.handle_turtle_pose,
                         self.turtlename)
        self.pub = rospy.Publisher('turtle_point_stamped', PointStamped)
    


if __name__ == '__main__':
    rospy.init_node('tf_turtle_stamped_msg_publisher')
    rospy.wait_for_service('spawn')
    spawner = rospy.ServiceProxy('spawn', turtlesim.srv.Spawn)
    spawner(4, 2, 0, 'turtle3')

    pp = PointPublisher()

    pub = rospy.Publisher("turtle3/command_velocity", turtlesim.msg.Velocity)
    while not rospy.is_shutdown():
        pub.publish(turtlesim.msg.Velocity(1,1))
        rospy.sleep(rospy.Duration(0.1))
```

It would also be great to add to the tutorial that the following lines should be added to CMakeLists.txt (assumes the file with code is named "turtle_msgfilter.cpp").

```
rosbuild_add_boost_directories()
rosbuild_add_executable(turtle_msgfilter src/turtle_msgfilter.cpp)
rosbuild_link_boost(turtle_msgfilter signals)
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/59066/updates-for-tf::messagefilter-example-in-geometry_tutorials/) by [dougbot01](https://answers.ros.org/users/2842/dougbot01/) on ROS Answers with karma: 342 on 2013-03-24

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Thanks for the corrections, @dougbot01.

To update the ROS geometry stack:

1. [Create a new issue](https://github.com/ros/geometry/issues) explaining the problem. Link to this question to avoid repetition.
2. Fork the [ros/geometry](https://github.com/ros/geometry) repository.
3. Apply your changes.
4. Submit a github pull request.

To update the wiki, log in and make those changes.

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2013-03-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dougbot01](https://answers.ros.org/users/2842/dougbot01/) on 2013-04-01**:
Thanks for pointing me in the right direction! My pull request was already merged into geometry_tutorials.